# HTTP responses in API Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is my first time working with RAILS and developing API. I am done with the code and basically look like this:

In the controller side:

```
class Api::V1::EnergyController < ApplicationController
    skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token

    def index

    end

    def create
        # Loading data in this part

        # Doing some calculations for the loaded data (Loops and ifs)

        #Outputs (organizing the output data) 


        # Render JSON - Output data
        render json: response_hash

    end 

end
```

I have been watching some tutorials and reading and they always include HTTP responses(in this way: `render json:{status: 200, message: "success"}.to_json`). For the error messages as well in the same form. In my code, I don't have any of such HTTP entries/lines of code. However, when the API finishes running it pops up the following message:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Etag: W/"6e509fca130161acdbef91f0013f7726"
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
X-Request-Id: 0d59ea00-b032-42ae-a28a-3fb6e31b5a59
X-Runtime: 28.173758
Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.2.2/2015-04-13)
Date: Wed, 27 May 2015 13:02:58 GMT
Content-Length: 1552
Connection: Keep-Alive
Set-Cookie: request_method=POST; path=/
```

My question is, should I add those HTTP responses in that way? It is that neccesary?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking - the code above will produce an HTTP response. Please clarify.

Comment: I have edited my question, maybe now it is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per coding standards you need to add status code to each response. The way you mentioned is not correct.

Correct way to add status code in responses

```
render :status => "200", :json => {:message => "success"}.to_json
render :status => "400", :json => {:status => "Unauthorized Access"}.to_json
```

Comment: You're not required to explicitly provide a status code unless you need it to be different than the conventions used by Rails.

Comment: Your answer help me a lot. Make sense to render for example: error at the beginning of the code? In my code I see that loading the data would be a failure point

Answer (score 4):

You are not required to explicitly provide a status code with your response unless you need it to be different from the conventions used by Rails.

For example, when you do

```
render json: { message: 'success' }
```

Rails will be default set the status code to `200` as you've already seen based on your original question. You can however be explicit about what status code you want returned

A common code block in a `create` action would be

```
def create
  @model = SomeModel.new(create_params)
  if @model.save
    render json: @model, status: :created
  else
    render json: { errors: @model.errors.full_messages }, status: :unprocessable_entity
end
```

Thus, if the model passes validations and is successfully saved to the DB, we respond with a JSON representation of the model and explicitly set the `status` to `:created` which is `201`.

If the model fails to save to the DB, we respond with the errors and explicitly set the status to `:unprocessable_entity` which is `422`.

Hope this helps.